# Visual Basic: Comma, ')',or valid expression continuation expected

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I have the following function:

```
Public Function HasCurrencyChanged(ByVal idPriceList As Integer, ByVal data As Dictionary(Of String, String)) As Boolean

        Dim param As ParamStruct() = New ParamStruct(2) {}

        Try
            param(0) = ProviderFactory.CreateParameter("@idPriceList", DbType.String, ParameterDirection.Input, idPriceList)
            param(1) = ProviderFactory.CreateParameter("@ID", DbType.String, ParameterDirection.Input, data["uidIDCurrency"])
```

In my C# class i call this method as  `_clsPriceList.HasCurrencyChanged(Convert.ToInt32(priceListId), data);`

In the last line i get a red line in `data["uidIDCurrency"]` telling me  Comma, ')',or valid expression continuation expected

What is wrong?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you may have translated some C# but failed to do so completely. You don't use brackets, i.e. `[]`, to index in VB but rather parentheses, i.e. `()`. You should have known that from any beginners VB tutorial or the like or even the rest of your own code that you posted.

Comment: Just Added the C# code